# How to manage specificity issues using ITCSS and having forms?

Tags: css, sass, oocss, itcss

I have a large project, structuring its CSS architecture via ITCSS. All in all, I love it. However, I have one issue when styling forms.

I've styled different form elements in my elements layer:

in **forms.scss**:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  // sexy element styles
}
```

However, if I have a component that needs different styling:

in **foo_component.scss**:

```
.c-foo__text, .c-foo__password {
  // sexy component styles
}
```

Due to the selectivity of the input type in forms.scss, my component styles in `foo_component.scss` do not override the element styles in `forms.scss`.

The current refactor I'm thinking of is changing `forms.scss` to an object:

**form_object.scss** refactor:

```
.o-form__text, .o-form__password {
  // sexy object styles that will be overwritten by the lower component
}
```

I was wondering if this is a proper convention, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is caused by the fact you're declaring a very specific styling (`input[type="text"]`) in `forms.scss` quite hight in the specificity graph.

In the ITCSS, we start with the most generic styles and we end with the most explicit ones.

[image]

Moreover, lets look at the inverted pyramid layers:

[image]

I believe in the perfect case scenario you should apply your logic in the **Generic**, **Base** and the **Components** layers.

So, based on all this, having only the limited info you shared - I would advice you to refactor it this way:

1. Form styling in the **Generic layer**: Move any form / input related reset styles here. Use only global resets (like `normalize.css` or `reset.css`). These are ground zero styles. You could use a specific selector like `input[type="text"]`, but only to reset style, not to add theme or anything related.
2. Form styling in the **Base layer**: Unclassed form elements comes here. Apply generic `form` or `input` styles here, that are shared across all elements. Do not use selector like `input[type="text"]` to style something that you would want to change on another element. Place only common styles here.
3. Form styling in the **Components layer**: Here is where your UI styles should be placed. Consider moving the `// sexy element styles` you're talking about here, assigning them to a class, like `.form-control` let's say. Below this class, add your other more specific class / UI modifiers.

In conclusion, note, that the decision depends from your specific use-case. There is no hard convention that can solve your issues. You need to make a decision based on all the project info you have. Different approaches would make sense in different stylesheet set-ups.

Anyways, if anything else fails, you could always reach ot to the **Trumps** layer :-)